# please help with a mathematical recreational problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to compute the area of a right trangle with base 2 and 3, but I want to test the truth of integration of the polar coordinate, so i decide to use this integration formula: $$\int_{0}^{\arctan \frac{3}{2}} \int_0^{\frac{2}{\cos \theta}} r^2 r\;\mathrm{d}r\;\mathrm{d}\theta$$ but with Wolfram Alpha's [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%5Earctan%282%2F3%29_0+integral+%5E2%2F%28cos+theta%29+_0+r%5E3+dr+d+theta), I get a weird result which differs by 0.06...
That make me suspect the truth of the polar coordinate.

Comment: Try it without that $r^2$ in the integrand.

Comment: How about "testing polar integration" on $\int \sqrt{\tan (x)}$??

Comment: Seems like a bit of an accusatory stance to take, to assume that your teachers (or the web, whatever the case may be) taught you something false. Perhaps you should phrase your question a bit more open-mindedly to the possibility that you made a mistake in your setup or computations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected:  The area element doesn't have the $r^2$ in it, so the integral should be $\int_{0}^{\arctan \frac{3}{2}} \int_0^{\frac{2}{\cos \theta}} r\;dr\;d\theta$.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%5Earctan%283/2%29_0%20integral%20%5E2/%28cos%20theta%29%20_0%20r%20dr%20d%20theta) says this is $3$.

Comment: If $\theta$ is the angle subtended at $(0,0)$ by $(3,0)$ and $(3,2)$, then surely $\tan\theta=2/3$. I think the triangle goes $(0,0)$ to $(2,0)$ to $(2,3)$, and the limits of integration were correct in the original.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  you are right.  Either set of limits gives the same answer (as it should-it is just repositioning the triangle).  I have updated the limits to match OP.